# Cannot import a function from a module in python

Tags: python, python-import

I'm using this code.

```
from azlyrics import artists
print(artists("O"))
```

In the module named 'azlyrics' the function 'artists' is well defined. But I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\python\eminem\New folder\azlyrics-master\examples\get_artists.py", line 1, in <module>
    from azlyrics import artists
ImportError: cannot import name 'artists' from 'azlyrics' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\azlyrics\__init__.py)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I installed azlyrics via pip. It is in Python/3.7/Lib/site-packages

Comment: In the module named 'azlyrics' the function 'artists' is well defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be a bug in the [`azlyrics`](https://pypi.org/project/azlyrics/) documentation or packaging.

This works:

```py
>>> from azlyrics.azlyrics import artists
>>> artists("O")
'["Oakenfold, Paul", "Oakes, Ryan", "Oak Ridge Boys,
The", "Oak, Winona", "O.A.R. (Of A Revolution)", "Oasis", "Obel, Agnes", "Oberst, ...]'
```

There is a mistake in azlyrics v1.3.2, relative import should be used in `azlyrics/__init__.py`:

instead of:

```py
from azlyrics import *
```

we should have:

```py
from .azlyrics import *
```

This is fixed but a release is not done.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please elaborate the problem sot it can be fixed.

Comment: @ASWINVENU, are you the author of this lib? No sure I have time for that…

Comment: No I'm not. But if you can't spare time you could just give me the keyword related to the bug so I can search the web.

Comment: @ASWINVENU, see this commit: https://github.com/adhorrig/azlyrics/commit/97b3fe6f6ee541c122cc8b88a66cb5ea5b0b75ff